# Facebook "like" button stopped working, if user is concurrently logged into Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My site has a concurrent FB app, and I had over 180 likes on my homepage. Suddenly, in the past month or so, the like count has disappeared and it acts as if there are no likes, if I am concurrently signed into FB. It shows me the number of likes if I sign out of FB, and visit the site again. I have posted this issue on FB developers forum as well, but have not received a resolution. I have double checked the app ID and run the debug tool, and it works correctly, but on my site the like button is malfunctioning.